# Updated Photoshop, found a big problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alignment

I haven't been here for a while. I updated my Photoshop from 2015 to 2023 version and found a problem that frustrates me a lot.

For example, I add just a simple rectangle, and after I need to change the size of this rectangle a bit. When I change the size (just for a few px), the Extras (blue guides around the rectangle, idk how to name it correctly) just go out of the pixels. It's very hard to explain, but these guides always help me to align objects and make them perfect (like 50x50px, 10x10, etc.)
I turned on Snap Vector Tools and Transform to Pixel Grid, in the 2015 version everything worked fine.

Thank you for your help! Please ask me any question, if you have to get more details. I hope you can help me to fix this problem.

[image]

Comment: Instead of using the Transform tool, use the Rectangle Shape Tool to resize the rectangle.